# C++ Function Nested Templates

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, generic-programming, qlist

I would like to write a function that can receive both QList and QVector of any type:

```
QList<int> iList;
QVector<int> iVector;
QList<double> dList;
QVector<double> dVector;
```

all these types must support invocation

```
my_func(iList); my_func(iVector); my_func(dList); my_func(dVector);
```

My solution

```
template <template <typename Elem> typename Cont>
void my_func(const Cont& cont)
{
    qDebug() << cont.isEmpty();
    Elem el = cont.first();
    qDebug() << el;
}
```

is not compiled:

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
```

What is the proper form of such template function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

```
template <template <typename> class Cont, typename Elem>
//                            ^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
void my_func(const Cont<Elem>& cont)
//                     ^^^^^^
{
    qDebug() << cont.isEmpty();
    Elem el = cont.first();
    qDebug() << el;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler only considers the primary class templates when it tries to locate a match, thus it doesn't know what `Elem` is for this line,

```
Elem el = cont.first();
```

as `Elem` is not what is being specialised.

Use either of the following solutions,

```
template <class Elem, template <class> class Cont>
void my_func(const Cont<Elem>& cont) { ... }

template <class Cont> void my_func(const Cont& cont) {
    typename Cont::value_type el = cont.first();
}
```

Comment: `Cont::value_type` should be `typename Cont::value_type`.

Comment: And here is a typo: `my_func(const Cont& cont); {`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the nested template argument, and you can use `auto` to retrieve the element.

```
template <typename Cont>
void my_func(const Cont& cont)
{
    qDebug() << cont.isEmpty();
    auto el = cont.first();
    qDebug() << el;
}
```

Note that you'll need to specify the C++0x or C++11 standard when compiling.